# Sum a Nested List with condition in python

Tags: python, sum, nested-lists

In order to simplify the reading of information for all other users, I would like to reduce a nested list where names appear in duplicate.
Concrete example:

```
[['savoielibrercgcm', '0.25'], ['MeriFer', '0.25'], ['XlassII', '0.25'], ['Tomixt_31', '0.25'], ['Tomixt_31', '0.25'], ['Tomixt_31', '0.25']]
```

(The value is not always equal to 0.25)

The ideal would be to be able to add the content according to the nickname to obtain a list like this:

```
[['savoielibrercgcm', '0.25'], ['MeriFer', '0.25'], ['XlassII', '0.25'], ['Tomixt_31', '0.75']]
```

I could easily do it with a for loop and an if condition. But the program being heavy and having to manage data in great quantity, I would like to be able to "optimize" this code.
I tried to go through a conversion to dict but that removes duplicate keys.

Do you have any ideas ? of the map? I must admit that I have never touched the map() :/

Thanks in advance for the help ^^'

Comment: How do you want to handle two names that map to different values?

Comment: A for loop is fine, a for loop is just as optimized as `map`. But in either case, this is a class grouping operation, using the `dict` grouping idiom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a solution using `collections.Counter`:

```
from collections import Counter

c = Counter()
for name, value in inputs:
    c[name] += float(value)
```

then you can convert the accumulated values for the name to string again. Counter works just like the built-in `dict`. I'm not sure if your task can be accomplished in a more performant way.

Comment: Even simpler, the input already consists of values suitable for creating single-item `Counter` instances, which themselves can be added together. `c = sum((Counter(x) for x in inputs), start=Counter())`.

Answer (score 0):

Using an dictionary to group the names should work for this:

```
L = [['savoielibrercgcm', 0.25], ['MeriFer', 0.25], ['XlassII', 0.25],
     ['Tomixt_31', 0.25], ['Tomixt_31', 0.25], ['Tomixt_31', 0.25]]

grouped = dict()
grouped.update((name,grouped.get(name,0)+value) for name,value in L)
L = [*map(list,grouped.items())]

print(L)
[['savoielibrercgcm', 0.25], ['MeriFer', 0.25], ['XlassII', 0.25], 
 ['Tomixt_31', 0.75]]
```

*Note: I assumed you don't really want your numerical values to be stored as strings*

Answer (score 0):

You could do this using an intermediate dictionary like this:

```
from collections import defaultdict

mydict = defaultdict(int)
mylist = [['savoielibrercgcm', '0.25'], ['MeriFer', '0.25'], ['XlassII', '0.25'], ['Tomixt_31', '0.25'], ['Tomixt_31', '0.25'], ['Tomixt_31', '0.25']]
for name, value in mylist:
    mydict[name] += float(value)
newlist = [[k, f'{v:.2f}'] for k, v in mydict.items()]
print(newlist)
```

**Output:**

```
[['savoielibrercgcm', '0.25'], ['MeriFer', '0.25'], ['XlassII', '0.25'], ['Tomixt_31', '0.75']]
```